# Relase build getting crashed but debug is working fine

Tags: android

I am getting error of null in release build only. But when I am creating a release build it is getting crashed but working fine in debug mode.

When I was optimizing my apk i deleted mobile_navigation.xml file but it was never used anywhere

Here is my build file

```
//one signal integration

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.12.5'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}
//end of one signal integration
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.codon.masterpiece"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 110
        versionName "4.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        manifestPlaceholders = [
                onesignal_app_id               : 'a33a085c-d32d-4462-a850-334f5c73db01',
                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                onesignal_google_project_number: 'REMOTE'
        ]


    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            //shrinkResources true
            //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            res.srcDirs =
                    [
                            'src/main/res/layouts/home_and_fragments',
                            'src/main/res/layouts/login_and_onboarding',
                            'src/main/res/layouts',
                            'src/main/res'
                    ]
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.0.0'

    //addedd libraries due to conflict
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0'

    //card view
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'

    //Facebook sdk
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.2.0'

    //Google login
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'

    //Play Store core library
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.6.1'

    //Recyclerview
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'

    //Retrofit
//    implementation('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.1') {
//        // exclude Retrofit’s OkHttp dependency module and define your own module import
//        exclude module: 'okhttp'
//    }
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.1'
    // exclude Retrofit’s OkHttp dependency module and define your own module import

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.12.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.1'
//    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.1.1'
//    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.1.1'

    //Volley
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'

    //circle image view
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'

    //image crop library
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.0'

    //Picasso
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

    //currency and country picker
    //implementation 'com.github.midorikocak:currency-picker-android:1.1.9'
    //implementation 'com.github.yesterselga:country-picker-android:1.0'

    //country picker
    implementation 'com.github.mukeshsolanki:country-picker-android:2.0.1'

    //imageview zoom
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.0.0'

    //one signal
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.11.2'

    //google analytics
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:17.0.0'

    //walkthrough
    implementation 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.4.3'

    //progressbar
    //implementation 'com.bigkoo:svprogresshud:1.0.6'


    //facebook shimmer effect
    implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.4.0'

    //progress bar

    implementation 'com.kaopiz:kprogresshud:1.2.0'



}
```

Here is my logcat

```
 Process: com.codon.masterpiece, PID: 13865
    java.lang.NullPointerException: throw with null exception
        at com.codon.masterpiece.d.b.b.a(Unknown Source:3)
        at com.codon.masterpiece.ui.home.e$d.a(:341)
        at f.g$b$a$a.run(:83)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6746)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Please suggest me what might be wrong in the release mode

Answer (score 0):

Add SerializedName in every field of models which are used in the serialization process by Gson.

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Example {

    @SerializedName("fieldName")//Add this line for all fields, the name passed in SerializedName should be a key in json
    private String fieldName;

    public String getFieldName() {
        return fieldName;
    }

    public void setFieldName(String fieldName) {
        this.fieldName = fieldName;
    }
}
```

**Or**

You can keep that model in progaurd rule

```
-keep class com.codon.masterpiece.model.Example { *; }//use the package name and class name for the models
```

Comment: But i have so many models and every model has variable with @SerializedName